# Is there software to stitch together a high number of small digital images without rotating or stretching them?

Tags: perl, image-processing, image-stitching

I have a very high number of small images (360x192), taken in sequence as screenshots from a DOS 2D computer game. They have decent overlap and i'd like to stitch them together into one big composite. Due to their very nature each subsequent image will fit pixel-perfect over the next or previous one. As such no rotation, stretching or distortion is required OR desired.

There is a lot of software out there to stitch together photo panoramas. But sadly all of them apply some distortion, even when they're explicitly instructed not to do so.

Is there software that will try to do pixel-perfect stitching?

Comment: You could easily write a program to do it. Tell us what languages you can use.

Comment: Pretty much only Perl, though i'm fairly good with that. I did consider it, but didn't really know where to start.

Comment: Sorry, Perl is one area where I'm totally clueless. I've added the tag to get some attention to the question.

Comment: You might want to look into projects that stitch microscope images together. They are solving the same kind of issue, i.e. creating a big image from parts without distortions. Have a look at https://har2009.org/program/events/149.en.html

Comment: The PDF of that talk seems to be broken. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica 8 features functions to do that:

```
ImageAlign[img1, img2, "Transformation" -> "Translation"] 
FindGeometricTransform[img1, img2, "Transformation" -> "Translation"]
```

By setting the option "Transformation" to "Translation" you are guaranteed that the result transformation will not have any of the "distortions" you are mentioning.

More examples in the documentation:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageAlign.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html

I know one can link Mathematica to perl, but I have not tried it yet.

**EDIT:** Using the link you sent, I came up with the following. The only problem is that you need to specify in advance the size of the output---NB I tried only the first 10 images.

```
directory = "~/Downloads/done/";
files = FileNames["*.bmp", directory];

canvas = ImagePad[Import[files[[1]]], {{100, 100}, {500, 100}}, Transparent];
Do[
    i = Import[f];
    fun = FindGeometricTransform[canvas, i, "Transformation" -> "Translation"];
    If[Head@fun === FindGeometricTransform,
        Continue[]
    ];
    canvas = ImageCompose[
               canvas,
               ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i, fun[[2]], DataRange -> Full, PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[canvas]}], Padding -> Transparent], 
               {1, 1, -1}],
 {f, files[[;; 10]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: FindGeometricTransform works really well and can even deal with brightness differences. However when assembling things with ImageCompose, it only extends the resulting image horizontally, not vertically. Any suggestion?

Comment: I feel we are very close from the result you want. You may like to post two images so that I can help with the exact syntax for the final composition. Else you may benefit from an example of image stitching which is in the slide #18 of the presentation at http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7967/

Comment: You can get a few hundred sample images here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10190786/done.zip I'm trying to combine them into one contiguous image, to which i can later add another arbitrary number of images. Right now i'm considering just letting Mathematica extract relations via the command line for me, so i can do some further processing like lightness adjustment and cutting out of the clock/cursor to the images, but if you could show some way to do that, it would be very interesting.

Comment: I've gotten this far and am fairly happy with the output: gist.github.com/8848a25a15da013ed1ad Only issue is that it prints some debug stuff whenever a position relation is printed. Can't find any info on how to turn that off.

Comment: @Mithaldu See my edit. Weird the question has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the definitive libraries to do panorama stitching is [Panorama Tools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/). You can either port or call from Perl.

Note that your specification is at odds. Unless you images are 100% rectilinear (i.e., taken 1:1 by an imager the same size as the image) you MUST compensate for the lens distortion. To accurately stitch photos together (pixel by pixel) the image needs compensating distortion.

Comment: I tried that already and even when running the optimizer only on X and Y, it will do sub-pixel shifting and yaw/pitch/rotation. Also, my images are screenshots from a 2D computer game. There never was any lense involved. I've clarified my question on that.

Comment: You can also set Panotools to do no image adjustment. I have used it in this mode to stitch flat bed scans together.

Comment: Could you detail the settings you used?

Comment: On the command line (GUI tools mostly do not have this) set a=b=c=0. This set a rectilinear image.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i did with hugin. Ran the optimizer with all disabled aside from X/Y. It has a massive input tab for that. Didn't help though. And there was no option to disable sub-pixel shifting in the first place.

Comment: Did you try PTStitcher directly? Perhaps hugin did not believe you?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know how to use PTStitcher. I was happy to get Hugin to generate 99% correct results.