# Finding exact image area matches

Tags: c#, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch together a series of images created from multiple screen captures of a very large image. The user moved vertically and horizontally at maximum resolution over the source image and took screenshots (including window borders, taskbar, etc.) with some overlap, and wants to put them together again.

There are existing solutions that will stitch photos together, but my case is much simpler than creating a panorama of independent photos because the images match *exactly*.

I am struggling to come up with an efficient algorithm that will find the largest matching rectangle common to adjacent images. Is there an existing solution or can someone suggest a way?

Comment: Related: [Is there software to stitch together a high number of small digital images without rotating or stretching them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9104649/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using pseudocode from [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) to find matches. This finds horizontal matches when I store the bitmap in a 1 dimensional array, but not vertical matches.